# Android sending message to BLE A2DP device

Tags: android, bluetooth, a2dp, avrcp

I have a device (ESP32) that has a Bluetooth module. I found some library to use on it and it acts as A2DP sink, works perfectly with Spotify app. My objective is to be able to send some small packages of data to it from my Android phone (device name, notifications, etc) while Spotify app is streaming media to it. What would be the best way of doing that? I tried to approach this with `MediaSession.setMetadata` method, but it seems it only works with actual media playback.